# How to know how many uploads a user makes to SoundCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, upload, soundcloud

In my app, users have the functionality of uploading a recording they made onto SoundCloud. Is there a way for me to know how many songs have been uploaded through my app? When a user tries uploading a song, they have to sign in and it asks "Allow 'APPNAME' to access your account?" so I'm assuming there is some way. But I can't find one, either programatically or on SoundCloud's website. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you should create a method that logs the new song into your own server (Assuming you have one) and then launch that method in the action that happens when the user wants to upload a song. Then just continue on with the uploading process. Problem solved. Or is there something more specific you want to do?

Comment: Yes, this would work, and I will probably do this. I just thought that since it asks for access there might be an easier way to see this, or to be able to see all songs uploaded through my app. Thank you though!

Comment: I see. So you are looking for an API-based solution then?

Comment: Yes, I was. But I figured it out!

Comment: Great! Since it apparently wasn't one of the below answers, then you should add your resolution as an answer. It might help other users. :) Glad you solved your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `api.soundcloud.com/apps/:app_id/tracks` to get all the tracks uploaded by that app, but it doesn't tell you the totals.

Comment: alright, figured it out. I had to get my app ID, but its actually http://api.soundcloud.com/apps/app_id/tracks?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

Comment: if you'd like, you can edit your answer to use the URL I just gave you and I'll give you the checked answer because you led me in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

Use *web scraping*, on the page of a soundcloud-profile there's a listitem with the classes `sc-ministats sc-ministats-large` and `sc-ministats-sounds`.
For example: `<li title="12 sounds" class="sc-ministats sc-ministats-large sc-ministats-sounds"> 12 </li>`

Scrape the webpage of someone's profile and parse the value of the li-element. Maybe take a look at this: [How to parse HTML on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)

Comment: The problem with the new soundcloud is that all the data is not displayed on the page, it loads dynamically. If you scrape their page, you don't get everything.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment! I'm pretty new to this stuff and I was completely unaware there were ways to parse HTML...I have been using good-old string manipulation to get what I want from HTML code in my apps haha.